# Angular4/Jasmine/Karma/PrimeNG/DataTable TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'scrollHeight' of object

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, primeng

I am receiving the following error while trying execute Angular test case.

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'scrollHeight' of object '[object HTMLElement]'
>               at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.DefaultDomRenderer2.setProperty (webpack:///~/@angular/platform-browser/@angular/platform-browser.es5.js:2923:0 <- src/test.ts:32458:18)

```
HTML Element : <p-dataTable [value]="xxx" [scrollable]="true" filter="true" [globalFilter]="xxx" (onFilter)="xxx" scrollHeight="{{myHeight}}">
```

The test case works fine if the scrollHeight set to a constant like `400px`. But externalizing it with `myHeight="400px"` does not work

I do not get this error in my application, this happens only in unit test case.

Comment: have you tried like this `[scrollHeight]="myHeight"`?

Comment: Documentation also states scrollHeight  is read only: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight

Answer (score 0):

Add the `TableModule` to `imports` in the spec

```js
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';

beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TableModule,

      ],
```